# Why does Google show sitelinks for our brand with an "s" at the end, but not when it isn't plural?

Tags: google, google-search-console, ranking, sitelinks

The name of our company is G2 Builders - What is happening is that if you go to google and type in "G2 Builder" with no "s" at the end, our website has sitelinks.

When you type in our name with the "s" G2 Builders, we do not get sitelinks. My question is, does anyone know how I can fix this?

Answer (score 2):

I have not found any way to adjust sitelinks, or even whether they are included or not.

According to [this page](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=47334) Google says the entire process is automated, and all you can do is 'demote' a page for up to 90 days at a time, so you do have the ability to remove a sitelink from your search result if you don't want that page to appear, but other than that Google doesn't give us any control over them.

Comment: Sherwin, thanks for your answer, I was hoping that wasn't the case, but I hope Google can recognize it is putting our sitelinks on a similar keyword but not our main word. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: No problem. I have also wondered about sitelinks before, and realized that you have no say in it at all. This is one of those things where Google thinks they know best. 

Also, I see you're new to Pro Webmasters. You can select an answer as being the "accepted answer" by clicking the check mark on the left of any answer posted on questions you ask.

Answer (score 0):

Sherwin is right. Google basically makes it up as it goes along but a lot of it seems to be on how well defined the information architecture of your site is.